# Dipole formation in electrostatic induction

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, inductance

Let's bring a positively charged rod near a conductor. Now since some electrons in outer shells are not strongly bound to atoms,they will get to the side near the rod. But why does it mean that dipole is formed in that conductor? We take the vertical cross sections of the conductor. Now,in each vertical layer,there will be atoms. So electrons from each vertical layer will get to the side of the rod. If that happens,except from the region closest to the rod,there will be positive charge in every cross section. Hence,apart from the very region towards the rod,the entirety of the conductor will be positively charged since electrons have left from each of the cross sections. As we can see dipole(*positive at one side and negative on another side*) hasn't been created,rather negative at a very small region and positive charges throughout the rest of the conductor.

The logic that the rod will push the positive charges at the extreme end also doesn't work since atoms are firmly immovable. So why is it still said that dipole is created as a result of electrostatic induction whereas we have proved that it isn't the case?

Answer (score 2):

In the case you are describing, there is a small patch of negative charge on one side of the conductor and the rest of the conductor is positively charged.  Is that necessarily true?  It depends on the shape of the conductor, and on how close we bring the positively charged rod to it.

But regardless of exactly how large the negatively charged region is and how large the positively charged region is, what you are describing is still a dipole.  Any time we have charge separation so that there is more positive charge in some region and more negative charge in another region we have formed a dipole.  The positively and negatively charged regions don't need to be the same size or shape for this to be a dipole.  The case where they are the same size and shape is just one of the simplest examples of a dipole, and the one which is the easiest to analyze mathematically.  So it is the most common example shown.